# Unregister Push notification token

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I just took over a code from a competitor, which has started on GCM.
But as the company I am going to create the app for, had made some bad decisions on their data basis (only made it possible to store on token per user), the app users has to unregister their tokens, so the company can store the tokens correctly.

On Android I am thinking, if this is enough

```
var instanceId = InstanceID.GetInstance(Android.App.Application.Context);
instanceId?.DeleteInstanceID();
```

And I have absolutely no idea of how to do it on iOS :(

iOS is registered as

```
public static void RegisterForPushNotification()
{
   if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
   {
      var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet());
      UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
      UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
   }
   else
   {
      UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
      UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
   }
}

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
   var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;

   var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

   NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
}
```

Windows on the 2nd hand is not registered, so I do not have to unregister from there and only register.

Answer (score 0):

> For iOS objective C

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>



@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

// [GCM register_for_remote_notifications]

@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *registrationKey;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *messageKey;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *gcmSenderID;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *registrationOptions;
```

**//  AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface AppDelegate ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) void (^registrationHandler)
(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error);
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL connectedToGCM;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString* registrationToken;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL subscribedToTopic;

@end


NSString *const SubscriptionTopic = @"/topics/global";


@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


 #if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)

    [self setUpGCMClientApp];

 #endif

    return YES;
}




-(void)setUpGCMClientApp{


    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    _registrationKey = @"onRegistrationCompleted";
    _messageKey = @"onMessageReceived";
    // Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
    // the services that have entries in the file
    NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
    if (configureError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error configuring the Google context: %@", configureError);
    }
    _gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Register for remote notifications
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
    // [START start_gcm_service]
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GCMConfig defaultConfig]];
    // [END start_gcm_service]
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    // Handler for registration token request
    _registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            weakSelf.registrationToken = registrationToken;
            NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
            [weakSelf subscribeToTopic];
            [ApplicationPreference saveValue:registrationToken forKey:KGCM_RegistrationToken];
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"registrationToken":registrationToken};
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                                object:nil
                                                              userInfo:userInfo];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startLocating:) name:@"ForceUpdateLocation" object:nil]; // don't forget the ":"

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"error":error.localizedDescription};
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                                object:nil
                                                              userInfo:userInfo];
        }
    };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:_messageKey
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:nil];





}



- (void)subscribeToTopic {
    // If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
    // topic
    if (_registrationToken && _connectedToGCM) {
        [[GCMPubSub sharedInstance] subscribeWithToken:_registrationToken
                                                 topic:SubscriptionTopic
                                               options:nil
                                               handler:^(NSError *error) {
                                                   if (error) {
                                                       // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                                                       if (error.code == 3001) {
                                                           NSLog(@"Already subscribed to %@",
                                                                 SubscriptionTopic);
                                                       } else {
                                                           NSLog(@"Subscription failed: %@",
                                                                 error.localizedDescription);
                                                       }
                                                   } else {
                                                       self.subscribedToTopic = true;
                                                       NSLog(@"Subscribed to %@", SubscriptionTopic);
                                                   }
                                               }];
    }
}



// [START disconnect_gcm_service]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    [[GCMService sharedInstance] disconnect];
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    _connectedToGCM = NO;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END disconnect_gcm_service]

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Could not connect to GCM: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        } else {
            _connectedToGCM = true;
            NSLog(@"Connected to GCM");
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            [self subscribeToTopic];
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_gcm_service]



// [START receive_apns_token]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSString *device_Token = [[NSString alloc] init];

    device_Token = [[[[deviceToken description]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken = %@",device_Token);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:device_Token forKey:kDEVICETOKEN];
    // [END receive_apns_token]
    // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the default config and request a registration
    // token to enable reception of notifications
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];
    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:_registrationOptions
                                                      handler:_registrationHandler];
    // [END get_gcm_reg_token]
}

// [START receive_apns_token_error]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Registration for remote notification failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    // [END receive_apns_token_error]
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"error" :error.localizedDescription};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:_registrationKey
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Handle the received message
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:_messageKey
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // Handle the received message
    // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:_messageKey
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END ack_message_reception]

// [START on_token_refresh]
- (void)onTokenRefresh {
    // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
    NSLog(@"The GCM registration token needs to be changed.");
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:_registrationOptions
                                                      handler:_registrationHandler];
}



// [END on_token_refresh]

// [START upstream_callbacks]
- (void)willSendDataMessageWithID:(NSString *)messageID error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        // Failed to send the message.
    } else {
        // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
    }
}

- (void)didSendDataMessageWithID:(NSString *)messageID {
    // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
}
// [END upstream_callbacks]

- (void)didDeleteMessagesOnServer {
    // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
    // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
    // server can resend those messages.
}




@end
```

Comment: Okay ;) 
Do you have any idea of how to transform it to C# (I am using Xamarin)

Comment: But where are the unregistering part in it?